# sql table pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to make a query that returns result for each employee on the whole month (30 days).
the data is as follows:

```
employeeID day DayDutyDate   fromTime                   Period
1           26  2014-03-26  2000-01-01 09:30:00.000     Time1
1           26  2014-03-26  2000-01-01 14:00:00.000     Time2
1           27  2014-03-27  2000-01-01 09:30:00.000     Time1
1           27  2014-03-26  2000-01-01 14:00:00.000     Time2
```

I am making pivot on days as follows:

```
PIVOT ( MIN(fromtime) FOR days IN ( [26],[27]) (I am being breif not listing all month days right now)
```

The result is as follows:

```
EmployeeID 26                       27
1          2000-01-01 09:30:00.000  null
1          2000-01-01 14:00:00.000  null
1          null                     2000-01-01 09:30:00.000  
1          null                     2000-01-01 14:00:00.000
```

What I need to have is :

```
EmployeeID 26                       27
1          2000-01-01 09:30:00.000  2000-01-01 09:30:00.000
1          2000-01-01 14:00:00.000  2000-01-01 14:00:00.000
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide the complete query?

Comment: Why does day 26 and 27 have the same from date? 2000-01-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT employeeID, [26], [27], Period
FROM 
(SELECT employeeID, [day], fromtime, Period
FROM #MyTable) p
PIVOT
(
MIN(fromtime)
FOR [day] IN
( [26], [27])
) AS pvt
```

produces this output:

```
employeeID  26                      27                     Period
==================================================================
1           2000-01-01 09:30:00.000 2000-01-01 09:30:00.000 Time1
1           2000-01-01 14:00:00.000 2000-01-01 14:00:00.000 Time2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dynamic SQL to Pivot the data. See the Example Below:

```
DECLARE @cols as varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql as varchar(max)

SELECT @cols  = coalesce(@cols  + ',','') + '[' + day + ']' FROM #MyTable

SET @sql = 
         'SELECT employeeID, ' + @cols + ', Period
           FROM (
                 SELECT employeeID, [day], fromtime, Period
                 FROM #MyTable
                 ) as P
           PIVOT 
                 (
                 MIN(fromtime)FOR [day] IN (' + @cols + ')
                 )AS pvt'

EXEC(@sql)
```